# Using jest.unmock to test a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, es6-promise

I am using Auth0 to manage authentication for my React App. Here's the function that I want to test:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.auth0.client.login({
            realm: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
            username,
            password,
        }, (err, authResult) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            if (authResult && authResult.idToken && authResult.accessToken) {
                resolve(authResult.idToken);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

`auth0` is instantiated in the following manner:

```
constructor(clientID: string, domain: string, redirectUri: string) {
    // Configure auth0
    this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        clientID,
        domain,
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        redirectUri,
    });
}
```

I have the following two tests:

- I want to see if I can instantiate the AuthService class.
- I want to see if I can login using a username/password combination

Here's the test file that I wrote:

```
jest.unmock('../AuthService');

import AuthService from '../AuthService';

describe('Auth0 Library', () => {
    test('Should be able to instantiate', () => {
        const auth0 = new AuthService('clientID', 'domain');
        expect(auth0).toEqual(expect.anything());
    });
});

describe('Auth0 Login', () => {
    test('Fetch token for existing user', () => {
        const auth0 = new AuthService('clientID', 'domain');
        auth0.login('email', 'pw')
            .then((idToken) => {
                console.log('idToken ', idToken);
                expect(auth0).toEqual(expect.anything());
            });
    });
});
```

The first test runs as expected. However, the second test never works. The promise that is returned is seemingly never resolved, and I never see the console.log.

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I am fairly new when it comes to writing jest tests.

Comment: What will happen if `err` is `false` and `authResult.idToken` is `0`, or `err` is `false` and `authResult.accessToken` is `null` (or other falsely value)?

Comment: @Arnial I will be decoding the jwt that I receive to ensure that it is indeed valid for the user that tried to sign in. Right now, I am more concerned with getting the tests to run, not with ensuring that the test is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution for using `Promise` and error-first callback together.

Folder structure:

```sh
.
├── AuthService.spec.ts
├── AuthService.ts
└── auth0
    ├── WebAuth.ts
    └── index.ts

1 directory, 4 files
```

E.g.

`AuthService.ts`:

```js
import * as auth0 from './auth0';

export class AuthService {
  private auth0: any;
  constructor(clientID: string, domain: string, redirectUri: string) {
    this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      clientID,
      domain,
      responseType: 'token id_token',
      redirectUri
    });
  }

  public login(username: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.auth0.client.login(
        {
          realm: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
          username,
          password
        },
        (err, authResult) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          if (authResult && authResult.idToken && authResult.accessToken) {
            resolve(authResult.idToken);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

`auth0/WebAuth.ts`:

```js
export class WebAuth {
  public client = {
    login(options, callback) {
      callback(null, {});
    }
  };
  constructor(...args: any) {}
}
```

`auth0/index.ts`:

```js
export * from './WebAuth';
```

`AuthService.spec.ts`:

```js
import { AuthService } from './AuthService';

const authService = new AuthService('clientid', 'domain', 'redirectUri');

describe('AuthService', () => {
  describe('#login', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
      jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });
    it('should login successfully and return id token', async done => {
      let loginCallback;
      jest.spyOn(authService['auth0']['client'], 'login').mockImplementation((options, callback) => {
        loginCallback = callback;
        done();
      });
      const actualValue = authService.login('username', 'password');
      const mAuthResult = { idToken: '123', accessToken: '321' };
      loginCallback(null, mAuthResult);
      await expect(actualValue).resolves.toBe('123');
    });

    it('should login failed', async done => {
      let loginCallback;
      jest.spyOn(authService['auth0']['client'], 'login').mockImplementation((options, callback) => {
        loginCallback = callback;
        done();
      });
      const actualValue = authService.login('username', 'password');
      const mError = new Error('network error');
      loginCallback(mError, null);
      await expect(actualValue).rejects.toThrowError(mError);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage for `AuthService.ts`:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/42137891/AuthService.spec.ts
  AuthService
    #login
      ✓ should login successfully and return id token (5ms)
      ✓ should login failed (2ms)

---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                 |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files            |       95 |      100 |     87.5 |    94.12 |                   |
 42137891-todo       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  AuthService.ts     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 42137891-todo/auth0 |    85.71 |      100 |    66.67 |    83.33 |                   |
  WebAuth.ts         |    83.33 |      100 |    66.67 |       80 |                 4 |
  index.ts           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.728s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/42137891